# Changed to a new version audioplayers package

Tags: flutter, audio

```dart
void playAudio() async {
    int result = await audioPlayer.play('assets/temp/forest.mp3', isLocal: true);
    if (result == 1) {
      // Success
      print('Forest audio played');
    } else {
      // Error
      print('Error playing forest audio');
    }
  }
```

For this code, we used a really old version of audioplayers package. The audio plays when you enter the page. Currently we are using the latest version of audioplayers, that is, version 5.2.0. In this page, the audio starts playing in an order. So what changes do we need to make to the audio player for the latest version?
The audio plays when you enter the page

Comment: can you clearly mentions what you want?

Comment: So code i have given for the audio player doesnt work for the newest version of the audioplayer package. I want to know the new syntax of the audioplayer for the latest version. I want the audio to play when you enter the page.

Comment: checkout this example from the official package page https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers/example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.